# C multidimensional array mirrors itself

Tags: arrays, c

In my attempts to make a character renderer, I stumbled upon the fact the array's constantly repeating itself without any obvious reason to do so.

```c
char screen[6][40] = {
    "                                        ",
    "                                        ",
    "                                        ",
    "                                        ",
    "                                        ",
    "                                        ",
};

void screenRedraw()
{
    clearScreen;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        printf("%s\n", screen[i]);
}

void main()
{
    screen[2][3] = 'g';
    screenRedraw();
}
```

The expected output would of course be one "g", yet it prints three!

```
                                                                                   g                                                                                                                                                            
                                           g                                                                                                                                                            
   g
```

I suspect the problem lies in `screen[2][3] = 'g'`, but have no clue on how to fix it.

Comment: The blanks strings given a length `[40]` are initialised with 40 spaces: this is legal and means there is no `'\0'` string terminator present. So `printf("%s\n", screen[i]);` isn't going to stop at the end of the string, because there isn't an end. It will carry on through memory until it finds a `'\0'`.

Comment: I'm guessing that big line of spaces has 40 spaces in it

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you, thank you, thank you. I somewhat knew that the null terminator is allocated some memory oftentimes, but didn't think it would be necessary during initialisation. Props to you for finding an error in this incredibly vague question.

Comment: A `char` array does not *have* to be a nul-terminated string (if it isn't passed to string handling functions), which is why the compiler only supplies the terminator if there is room. In that case, *all* the uninitialised memory is set to `0`, and it is not a specific feature of the `char` array. What is specific though, is if you don't specify a 1D array length, it is set to include a terminator.

Answer (score 1):

Do not hardcode spaces and do not use magic numbers in your loops, it is very prone to errors, `memset` can help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum {rows = 6, cols = 40};
static char screen[rows][cols + 1]; // + 1 for the trailing NUL

void initScreen(void)
{
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        memset(screen[row], ' ', cols);
    }
}

void screenRedraw()
{
    // clearScreen();
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", screen[row]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    initScreen();
    screen[2][3] = 'g';
    screenRedraw();
}
```

Comment: This response is for sure more of a "how to do X better" rather than "how to solve X doing Y", but i am all for it. Big thanks for all the advice!

Answer (score 1):

You could print exact count of characters:

```
void screenRedraw()
{
    clearScreen();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%.*s\n", 40, screen[i]);
    }
}
```

@edit typo - it's `%.*s` not `.*%s`

Comment: Well, that admittedly could've saved me, but it's not handling the error, and rather, preventing it, by limiting the character length. Quite a cool feature of ```printf``` though!